# Como publicar um website asp.net mvc 4 no iis6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

Eu dou um publish no visual studio 2012, adiciono um novo website no iis6, coloco o caminho da pasta dos arquivos publicados, mas quando vou acessar o site, abre a tela de login e quando clico em entrar a página fica em branco.
Como posso arrumar esse erro ou teria alguma maneira diferente de fazer isso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com [Can we deploy MVC 4 application on IIS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447136/can-we-deploy-mvc-4-application-on-iis-6) no SO-en, você precisa acessar no `IIS manager`: expandir o nó `IIS master`, e escolher o nó `Extensões de Serviço Web`.

Depois, no painel esquerdo do `IIS Manager`, clicar com o botão direito na extensão `ASP .NET v4.0`.

Depois clicar em permitir.

*Eu traduzi os termos, não sei se são os termos que aparecem em português. Se você está com o `IIS Manager` em inglês, siga o link acima.

Mais informações aqui também [ASP.NET MVC on IIS 6 Walkthrough](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx/).

Comment: ainda não funcionou .. :S